# Forbidden You don't have permission to access this resource. Apache/2.4.54 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1p PHP/8.2.0 Server at localhost Port 80

Tags: apache, xampp, htdocs, port80

I have tried every solution on the internet yet I cannot figure out how this error will go away.

"XAMPP Apache Service is already running on port 80" - Apache is running according to the XAMPP.

I also used "localhost" on the url, so I am not understanding what the problem is.

ISSUE:

Forbidden

You don't have permission to access this resource.
Apache/2.4.54 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1p PHP/8.2.0 Server at localhost Port 80

I went into the Apache config on XAMPP and changed everything to "Required all granted". Still did not work at all. I even tried to see if anything was wrong with my computer.

Comment: Port 80 is below port 1024.  These ports can only be used by root.  To start your Apache on port 80, you will have to setup a sudo.  Do NOT configure your Apache to be all root.  Configure it with a dedicated user, and sudo the start only.  You can research that, it is a common subject for Apache admin.